# Contravariance isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, contravariance

```
public interface IMyControl<in T> where T : ICoreEntity
{
    void SetEntity(T dataObject);
}

public class MyControl : UserControl, IMyControl<DataObject>   // DataObject implements ICoreEntity
{
    void SetEntity(T dataObject);
}
```

All fine so far, but why does this create null?

```
var control = LoadControl("~/Controls/MyControl.ascx"); // assume this line works
IMyControl<ICoreEntity> myControl = control;
```

myControl is now null...

Comment: All is not fine so far. This code doesn't even compile. Where is T declared in the second class? Was that indended to be DataObject instead of T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `dataObject` as parameter for this to work. Methods could only return it.

```
public interface ICoreEntity { }
public class DataObject: ICoreEntity { }

public interface IMyControl<out T> where T : ICoreEntity
{
    T GetEntity();
}

public class MyControl : IMyControl<DataObject>   // DataObject implements ICoreEntity
{
    public DataObject GetEntity()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can:

```
MyControl control = new MyControl();
IMyControl<ICoreEntity> myControl = control;
```

Comment: Isn't that covariance not contravariance?  I thought they introduced the out keyword in order for this to work?  It compiles anyway

Comment: Yes this is covariance, but the way you intend to use it is covariance. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx